# Does photon-photon scattering influence classical vacuum E&M dynamics?

Tags: electromagnetism, cosmology, quantum-electrodynamics, big-bang, cosmic-microwave-background

At a purely classical level, Maxwell's equations are completely linear, and associated with a linear coupling to a conserved current in the electrodynamical Lagrangian. When this Lagrangian is promoted to a quantum theory, the linear coupling permits 'emergent virtual interactions' between photons (at leading order, two photons meeting at a square loop carrying an electric charge), which has been observed experimentally [c.f....] primarily in the gamma sector (mainly from the absence of massless charged fermions), corresponding to a contact interaction at classical length scales and lowish energies, which might smear out (causally) at energies just below various pair-production threshold frequencies. In the perturbative limit, this corresponds to a local non-linearity in the Lagrangian density of the form
\begin{align*}
&\delta \mathcal L \propto \mathcal L_0^2 +\frac{7}{4}(E\cdot B)^2, \quad \mathcal L_0\equiv \frac{1}{2}(E^2 - B^2)\\
&_{{}_\text{source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Heisenberg_Lagrangian}}
\end{align*}
Has anyone explored solutions to the non-linear Maxwell equations, either numerically or analytically?  It might be interesting to map out their behavior at various scales (I would be especially keen to know what the effects might have been in the early universe, or if the effect could be or has been "simulated" locally with cavity experiments.)

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but two things to keep in mind. (1) As you said, the Lagrangians you wrote down are only valid in the small-field limit, so any solution you or someone else finds should be checked to verify that it does not leave the regime of validity of the approximation that let you use this Lagrangian in the first place. (2) These interactions are *extremely* small, at ordinary values of the fields, so you need extremely large fields (compared to everyday scales, not compared to the cutoff) for these terms to be relevant.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-photon_physics